# How do you get a regex to match part or all of one criteria and all of another?

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to write a regex which will match all or part of the first part of a query and all of the second part.

The text comes in the form of:

```
=S
==S-S
===DC1
===DC3
====REF
=====SUB=F
AB123-05.abc
```

It needs to match a line beginning with a `=` symbol.  There may be one to five lines each starting with one to five `=` symbols. The first part is to match the `=` symbol and the second part whhatever is after it.

The third part needs to match the last line:

```
AB123-05.abc
```

I started out with the regex:

```
([=]{1,5})(.+)
```

Which correctly matches the `=` symbols and whatever is after it but did not match the last line.

So, I changed it to:

```
([=]{1,5})(.+)(\n[\S]+\.abc)
```

which now only matches the last line and the line above. You can see what I have done here...

https://regex101.com/r/VtW9PY/2/

So basically the first match is to be line beginning with a `=` symbol (s) and the second match is the remainder of the line after the `=` symbol(s).
the third match is the last line.  There may not be any lines beginning with a `-` in which case the last line becomes the first match.

I'm doing this in VBA.

Comment: Try `^(?:={1,5}(.+)|(.*)$(?!.))` (use `RegExp.Multiline = True`)

Comment: Or use an optional capturing group for the third part if `AB123-05.abc` can also occur after each line that starts with an equals sign `^(=+)(.+)(?:\r?\n(\S+\.abc))?` https://regex101.com/r/4xtcrP/1/

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry took me a couple of days to get some other bits worted.  Yes it worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set `RegExp.Multiline = True` and then use the following regex:

```
^(?:={1,5}(.+)|(.*)$(?!.))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/05emV3/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (here)
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group so that `^` could apply to both the alternatives:

  - `={1,5}(.+)` - 1 to 5 `=` chars and then any 1+ chars other than a line break char as many as possible captured into Group 1 (`match.Submatches(0)`)
  - `|` - or
  - `(.*)$(?!.)` - any 0+ chars other than a line break char as many as possible captured into Group 2 (`match.Submatches(1)`) up to the end of the text. Note `$` can't be used since it will match the end of any line due to the `RegExp.Multiline = True`.
- `)` - end of the group.